# Text Overflow inside ROW widget doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

So I tried to put a text after an icon, so i use Row. But when I input the long text it does overflow the SizedBox. so i add TextOverflow, but the Textoverflow didn't work

Here's the code :

```
Row(
children: [
  Icon(
    Icons.location_on,
    size: 2.h,
    color: Color(0xFFE32346),
  ),
  Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
      child: Text(
        Address,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 1,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16.sp,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins'
        ),
      )
  ),
]),
```

Comment: if you row is inside any container?

Comment: @Manishyadav The row is Inside a Column

Comment: what are you trying to archive for largetext?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh im trying to put icons before text, and the overflow did not work inside the row

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is the example . please use Expanded in this use case

like this way

```
 Row(children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.location_on,
                size: 20,
                color: Color(0xFFE32346),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                 '     qqqqqqqqqqqqqq qqqqqqqqqqqqqq qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
              )),
            ]),
```

the output will be

[image]

Comment: why padding and screen utils are removed?

Comment: don 't remove screen utile , i am not using that plugin ,so i removed and

Comment: @nagendranag so you can still use padding but inside the Expanded

Comment: just inspect padding widget...... , you will get the answer ,and just inspect the expanded widget

Comment: @Macchiato I know we can add padding inside the Expanded ......I am just asking why that padding was removed ...to know if there are any specific reasons?

Comment: i noticed that  , in your use case the maxLines =1 so , don't put extra code ( padding widget )  to the code , so i remove it .......  if you want left spacing  , add a space inside the " " (codes) like this way ( '' space qqqqqqqqqqq qqqqqqq'') . only applicable for maxLines =1 and  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h) or margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h) these scenarios

Comment: ( '' verbally written space  qqqqqqqqqqq qqqqqqq'')

Comment: i  edited the answer , so you can understand this difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You should wrap your code inside  `Container`  ant than in a `Flexible` to let your Row know that it's ok for the `Container` to be narrower than its intrinsic width. `Expanded` will also work.

or

```
 Row(
 children: [
          Expanded(
       Icon()
           ),
        Expanded(
          Text()
           )

            
        ]),
```

Comment: Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ConstrainedBox is a built-in widget in flutter SDK.
Its function is to add size constraints to its child widgets,Wrap your text with ConstrainedBox and set widthconstraints

Please refer the following link

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html

Answer (score -1):

For row case, you can wrap `Padding` with `Expanded`. Or you can use `SizedBox` for spacing and wrap `Text` with `Expanded` to get available space.

```dart
Row(
 children: [
  Icon(..),
  // SizedBox(width: x),// if you dont use padding
  Expanded(
    child: Padding( 
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(..)
        child:  Text( Address,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      maxLines: 1,
    ),
  ),
]),
```